# Qt Mobility: Set Landscape Orientation And Full Screen

Tags: qt, nokia

i am new to Nokia Qt and having just started to develop App. I want to set Landscape Orientation & Full Screen mode for my App. 
Any Help??

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need symbian api to be included in the code in snippets 
if you are using Qt creator
see this file
http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS001517_-_Lock_application_orientation_in_Qt_for_Symbian
hope it helps!!!